# WebApiDataSourceRequestModelBinder multiple column sort query string parameter format

Tags: sorting, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working on an SPA which is communicating with an API that was originally designed to be used with Kendo UI controls. I am not using Kendo UI controls and I cannot modify the API implementation.

API methods that used to interact with a Kendo UI grid expect a `DataSourceRequest` object as a parameter, and is using `WebApiDataSourceRequestModelBinder` to bind to it.

I having paging and single column sorting working by passing a query string like:

```
?page=1&pageSize=10&sort=foo-asc
```

However I can't work out the query string format required for multiple column sort.

I have tried multiple sort parameters `&sort=foo-asc&sort=bar-desc` and comma delimited `&sort=foo-asc,bar=desc`.

What is the correct format so that the `WebApiDataSourceRequestModelBinder` can parse the query string parameters into the correct `DataSourceRequest` for multiple column sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct format is tilde delimited:

`&sort=foo-asc~bar-desc`